JS sort array of pair with null and empty values at the end
I have this array of pairs in JS :


    var my_array = [['line_1','2'],['line_2','0'],['line_3','5'],['line_4',''],['line_5','4'],]
    
var my_sorted_array =my_array.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])

console.log(my_sorted_array)



For now to sort it by second item I am using th code below
But I would like to put the blank/empty and null values to the end.
Expected result :
[['line_1','2'],['line_5','4'],['line_3','5'],['line_2','0']['line_4','']]

Thanks

Do you understand what the comparison function passed to sort is meant to return? (relevant documentation) Have you tried adjusting it?

The documentation shows the compareFn "should return a number where:
A negative value indicates that a should come before b.
A positive value indicates that a should come after b.
Zero or NaN indicates that a and b are considered equal.

" So you could likely use a conditional in your sort function to return a positive or negative value

You could replace each 0 value with Infinity while doing the sort comparisons:


let a = [['line_1','2'],['line_2','0'],['line_3','5'],['line_4',''],['line_5','4']];

a.sort(([,a],[,b])=>(+a||Infinity)-(+b||Infinity));

console.log(a);




I validate the Carsten Massmann answer because it's shorter and easier than mine. Thanks to him.
Here is another way do to it that I finally found :


var my_array = [['line_1','2'],['line_2','0'],['line_3','5'],['line_4',''],['line_5','4'],]
var my_sorted_array = my_array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a[1] === "" || a[1] === null || a[1] === "0") return 1;
    if(b[1] === "" || b[1] === null || b[1] === "0") return -1;
    if(a[1] === b[1]) return 0;
    return a[1] < b[1] ? -1 : 1;});
    
console.log(my_sorted_array)






    var my_array = [['line_1','2'],['line_2','0'],['line_3','5'],['line_4',''],['line_5','4'],]
    
var my_sorted_array =my_array.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])

console.log(my_sorted_array) // it will compile




Thanks but it doesn't sort with empty values and zero at the end of the array which is what I was looking for

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
